# Editable fields in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm a newbie to Spring MVC. Here's my question.
I have a input view where a user can input a name and a text, which will then be displayed like this:

```
    <tr>
     <td>Name: </td>
     <td>${product.name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Text: </td>
     <td>${product.text}</td>
    </tr>
```

How can I make the two fields editable for the user? I'd like to place a link or so next to each field, that the user can use for editing entries. 
Furthmore, I'd like to link the request to the same page as the input page/form, how can I distinguish the two cases in my controller? I'm using SimpleFormController...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<a href` tag as follows:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/editpage"/>">${product.text}</a>
```

Therefore, in your example above, you could use the following:

```
<tr>
 <td>Name: </td>
 <td><a href="<c:url value="/editpageforname"/>">${product.name}</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Text: </td>
 <td><a href="<c:url value="/editpagefortext"/>">${product.text}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Your edit page link urls will have to be the correct link to that edit page.

*Alternative:*
**However**, another way to make the fields editable is to use the spring `<form>` tags as below:

```
<form:input path="name" placeholder="${product.name}" />
<form:input path="text" placeholder="${product.text}" />
```

Comment: Does the placeholder tag work with Spring 2.5? And why did you put "${product.name}"  in the a href tag? This will just turn my linkname into the field name?

Comment: I don't think that Spring 2.5 supports the placeholder tag. Spring 3 and onwards should support it. I normally put the ${product.name} tag within the a tag because the value of ${product.name} would then appear as the link, which is always nice to see.

Comment: If I want to link it to the same page as the input page, how can I distinguish the cases in my controller? I'm using SimpleFormController...